# Why does having serializer in threadlocal result in memory leak in kafka producer?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, thread-safety

Consider the following setup

```
prop.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ThriftSerializer.class.getName());


public class ThriftSerializer implements Serializer<TBase> {
    private final ThreadLocal<TSerializer> serializer = new ThreadLocalTSerializer();

    @Override
    public void configure(Map map, boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String s, TBase event) {
        try {
            return serializer.get().serialize(event);
        } catch (TException e) {
            return new byte[0];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

The above code causes memory leak

But I am not understanding why it happen. Does kafka producer create alot of threads that don't die?

If the code above is replace with

```
@Override
public byte[] serialize(String s, TBase event) {
    TSerializer serializer = new TSerializer();

    try {
        return serializer.serialize(event);
    } catch (TException e) {
        return new byte[0];
    }
}
```

Then the memory leak goes away, which make sense but for each event its creating new object that needs to be garbage collected, potentially causing gc pressure if throughput is high

Can someone point me a direction in understanding this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware the KafkaProducer is thread safe and sharing a single producer instance across threads will generally be faster than having multiple instances.

But the send method is asynchronous (unless you call .get() on the Future object returned by the send method, which is not recommended, this way you will wait for each send and therefore process them in a synchronous manner).

Due to the documentation the producer consists of a pool of buffer space that holds records that haven't yet been transmitted to the server as well as **a background I/O thread that is responsible for turning these records into requests and transmitting them to the cluster**. Failure to close the producer after use will leak these resources.

It seems that the send method actually uses a background thread to transform your record and send it to the cluster.

Are you actually closing the producer at the end?

```
    producer.flush();
    producer.close();
```

The close method of the serializer is called when the Kafka session is to be closed.
My guess is that you could try to do some additional cleaning in the close method of the serializer or mark it as eligible for garbage collection.